# admin panel is not working after applying htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

since i have applied .htaccess to my folder to remove php extension

my admin panel name *nimda* like `http://www.xyz.com/nimda` is not working.

it shows this error message

> Not Found

The requested URL was not found on this server.

what to do.

```
RewriteEngine On 

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ xyz.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ xyz.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls 
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: **When having problems with mod_rewrite, please post the `RewriteLog` output** ..........

Answer (score 0):

That's because the last part of your htaccess rules are converting it to a file that doesn't exist.

```
# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls 
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

That rule is taking anything without .php and adding it to the file so your URL admin link is being written as `http://www.xyz.com/nimda.php` which does not exist, hence the 404 not found.

I'm not sure what you plan to accomplish with your rules but if you want your htaccess this way you can exclude the admin directory like this.

```
RewriteEngine On 

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /$1 [R=301,L] 

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ xyz.com/$1 [R=301,L] 

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/nimda [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```